# How to create class model for multiple collection in C#?

Tags: mongodb, model, .net-core

I trying to create web services for shop cart with `mongodb` and `dotnet core` web api. My cart collection have information of product. Product must be a multiple array or object and I tried with one solution but I have this error : 
 **An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'CartService' while attempting to activate 'CartsController'.**

This is looks collection of cart:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cab18a057ab66f2536feeb9"),
    "Status" : "Inactive",
    "Product" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ca9b27dbec46268305ce427"),
            "Quantity" : 1.0,
            "Name" : "Samsung",
            "Price" : 1000.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ca9b27dbec46268305ce427"),
            "Quantity" : 2.0,
            "Name" : "Samsung",
            "Price" : 9999.0
        }
    ],
    "modified_on" : "5/4/2019"
}
```

This is class model:

```
public class Cart
{   
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Product")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("modified_on")]
    public DateTime modified_on { get; set; }
}
```

Cart Service:

```
public class CartService
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Cart> _carts;

    public CartService(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(config.GetConnectionString("WebShopDb"));
        var database = client.GetDatabase("WebShopDb");
        _carts = database.GetCollection<Cart>("Carts");
    }

    public List<Cart> Get()
    {
        return _carts.Find(cart => true).ToList();
    }

    public Cart Get(string id)
    {
        return _carts.Find<Cart>(cart => cart.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public Cart Create(Cart cart)
    {
        _carts.InsertOne(cart);
        return cart;
    }

    public void Update(string id, Cart cartIn)
    {
        _carts.ReplaceOne(cart => cart.Id == id, cartIn);
    }

    public void Remove(Cart cartIn)
    {
        _carts.DeleteOne(cart => cart.Id == cartIn.Id);
    }

    public void Remove(string id)
    {
        _carts.DeleteOne(cart => cart.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Cart Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CartsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly CartService _cartService;

    public CartsController(CartService cartService)
    {
        _cartService = cartService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Cart>> Get()
    {
        return _cartService.Get();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id:length(24)}", Name = "GetCart")]
    public ActionResult<Cart> Get(string id)
    {
        var cart = _cartService.Get(id);

        if (cart == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return cart;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<Cart> Create(Cart cart)
    {
        _cartService.Create(cart);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetCart", new { id = cart.Id.ToString() }, cart);
    }

    [HttpPut("{id:length(24)}")]
    public IActionResult Update(string id, Cart cartIn)
    {
        var cart = _cartService.Get(id);

        if (cart == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _cartService.Update(id, cartIn);

        return NoContent();
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id:length(24)}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(string id)
    {
        var cart = _cartService.Get(id);

        if (cart == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _cartService.Remove(cart.Id);

        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, your product property needs to be a collection, your model has it as a single product and your bson shows it as an array. As for the error, your CartController expects a CartsService object but doesn't have one.

Comment: Products it is collection, but I didn't post this here.

Comment: If you want to pass an object into your controller contstructor like that, you need to configure it with your IOC container. .NET Core makes this incredibly easy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks. I solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register that service in IoC. The best way is the next:

Create interface **ICartService** with all methods you will have in CartService implementation:

```
public interface ICartService {
    List<Cart> Get();
    Cart Get(string id);
    Cart Create(Cart cart);
    void Update(string id, Cart cartIn);
    void Remove(Cart cartIn);
    void Remove(string id);
}
```

implement that interface in CartService.cs:

```
public class CartService : ICartService
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Cart> _carts;
```

**Register that service in Startup.cs** (since .NET Core has IoC included)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddScoped<ICartService, CartService>();
        ...
```

Quick explanation of object types (Scoped, Transient, Singleton):

> Transient objects are always different; a new instance is provided to
>   every controller and every service.
>
> Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across
>   different requests.
>
> Singleton objects are the same for every object and every request.

and change **CartsController** to:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CartsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICartService _cartService;

    public CartsController(ICartService cartService)
    {
        _cartService = cartService;
    }
```

and it should work.